# How to show save percent in app purchase subscription ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c

So i have weekly, monthly and yearly subscription plans what i want do is based on weekly price i want to save percentages for monthly and yearly.

```
- (NSString *)weeklyPrice:(SKProduct *)product {
    CGFloat factor = 0.23; //week factor 30/7 (30days divide by 7 days)
    if([product.productIdentifier isEqualToString:AR_WEEKLY_SUBSCRIPTION_PRODUCT_ID] ||) {
        factor = 0.23;
        _weeklyPrice = product.price;
    }
    else if([product.productIdentifier isEqualToString:AR_MONTLY_3DAY_SUBSCRIPTION_PRODUCT_ID]) {
        factor = 1.0;
    }
    else if([product.productIdentifier isEqualToString:AR_YEARLY_3DAY_SUBSCRIPTION_PRODUCT_ID] ) {
        factor = 12.0;
    }
    NSLog(@"divide by %@",[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithMantissa:factor exponent:0 isNegative:NO]); // here value getting 0 hence giving exception
    NSDecimalNumber *weeklyPrice = [product.price decimalNumberByDividingBy:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithMantissa:factor exponent:0 isNegative:NO]];

    NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
    [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    [numberFormatter setLocale:product.priceLocale];

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/week", [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:weeklyPrice]];
}
```

For save percent using below block of code

```
 (NSString *)savingPercent:(SKProduct *)product {
    CGFloat factor = 0.23;
    //NSDecimalNumber *saving = nil;
    if([product.productIdentifier isEqualToString:AR_WEEKLY_SUBSCRIPTION_PRODUCT_ID] ) {
        return @"";
    }
    else if([product.productIdentifier isEqualToString:AR_MONTLY_3DAY_SUBSCRIPTION_PRODUCT_ID]) {
        factor = 1.0;
    }
    else if([product.productIdentifier isEqualToString:AR_YEARLY_3DAY_SUBSCRIPTION_PRODUCT_ID] ) {
        factor = 12.0;
    }

    CGFloat saving = 100.0-((product.price.floatValue/factor/_weeklyPrice.floatValue)*100);

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SAVE %.0f%%", saving];
}
```

[like in this image shows save perrcent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaOyg.png)
Any suggestions would be mode helpful

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking; you set the price in App Store connect. Are you asking how to dynamically calculate the discount percentage the user is getting bad on the difference between the weekly and monthly/annual prices?

Comment: @Paulw11 i have edited my question and i want to save percent for month and year based on weekly price